# clear loaded javascript with html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, garbage-collection

I'm loading html 'views'(code) with jquery.html(), these views have javascript code on them. When I load a different 'view' the functions from the previous view are still accessible. How do I clear them?

**EDIT**

```
 $("wrapper").html('<div class="some-class"></dv><script>var func = function(){ console.log('some thing') }</script>')


$("wrapper").html('<div class="some-class2"></dv><script>var func2 = function(){ console.log('some thing2') }</script>')
```

After The second, I can still access `func()`, Is there a way to clear that?

Comment: share the code sample

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: haven't really tried just figured that now. I was wondering what it is? cache?

Comment: Set your function as null in your second line: `func = null`

Comment: ok, so I need to clear all functions and variables before loading the second 'view'. thanks.